# Android customize Bottom navigation

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to implement a Bottom Navigation Bar in android. I have implemented the basic design and functionality but need to make a change in the design.

[image]

I need the center Icon to be Enlarged so that it looks something like the image above.
I cannot seem to find any way to do that.
Will i have to make a custom class for that?

Comment: @can you please post your code here

Comment: the android bottom navigation is a shitty un-usable stuff. cuz u will have to implement the stacks for every tab by urself !!! so dont use it. its more like a list of buttons and nothing more . make your own bottom navigation bro. Ive had that exprience ....

Answer (score 6):

You can use this library to achieve bottom navigation like this
https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View